# TypeError: _Captcha.write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

Tags: discord.py, captcha

I'm trying to create a captchat command but I can't. What I'd like is that when we do /verify it sends us a photo composed of 7 numbers in a private message and if we copy the 7 numbers on the photo to the identiquet it gives us the verify role and when we have the role we can't execute the command.

```
async def verify(ctx):
  sender = ctx.author
  image = ImageCaptcha(width = 280, height = 90)
  captcha_text = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
  captcha_text = str(captcha_text)
  data = image.generate(captcha_text)
  await ctx.send('look at your PM')
  image.write(captcha_text)
  await sender.send('ok its what the captcha', file=discord.File('captcha/CAPTCHA.png'))
  print(captcha_text)
  while True:
        msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda check: check.author.id == ctx.author.id)
        if msg.guild == None:
          break

  print(msg.content)
  if msg.content == captcha_text:
        await sender.send('Correct you have been checked!')
        role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Check')
        await sender.add_roles(role)
  else:
        await sender.send('Incorrect try again!')
```

and here are the errors that I obtain

File "f:\tout les dossier\discord tools\les logiciel\les mien\RAID\Anti Raid.py", line 188, in verify
image.write(captcha_text)
TypeError: _Captcha.write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

would you have the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Read the error. It's telling you that you need to specify where to output the image

In your case, replace the line

```py
image.write(captcha_text)
```

with

```py
image.write(captcha_text, 'captcha/CAPTCHA.png')
```

Comment: thanks it worked but now I have another error here it is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'captcha/CAPTCHA.png